LT8316 Multi-Output drop on 1 output under small load
I designed a Multi-Winding/Multi-Output Flyback to generate +40V and -225V. In my application, the outputs need to work in a flip-flop load, where only one output handles a variable load of 0 to 50W at a time, while the other remains lightly loaded (just for stability). I used the LT8316 with no-opto (PSR) feedback, as shown in the attached file (some components are equivalent).
For the transformer, I used the TDK B66229G1000X187, with approximate inductances shown in the attached LTspice circuit. The winding specifications are:

Primary: 46 turns of AWG 22 (bottom layer)
Aux: 7 turns of AWG 28
Sec (+40V): 12 turns of AWG 22
Sec (-225V): 68 turns of AWG 22 (top
layer)

I measured the leakage inductance at 13uH by shorting all the secondaries, including aux. This will make the K=0.98 (317/(317+6.5)).
Problem:
In simulation with K=0.98, the outputs regulate well under any load. However, in the real circuit, the +40V rail drops to about +5V with even a 10W load, while the -225V rail performs well up to 45W.
As a test, removing the rectifier diode from the +40v rail resulted in a decent -225V across various loads, but by removing the rectifier diode from the -225v rail, the +40V rail still dropped to +5V even under light load (1w).
In summary, the +40V rail has poor load regulation, while the -225V rail performs well. How this is possible and how to resolve? If the design is bad, how come -225v is performing well?
I've also attached my Schematic and PCB layout, which may not be ideal; however, even shortening paths (e.g., from aux to feedback resistor) has not improved performance.




Good post: have you got the dot polarity right on the 40 volt output winding?

You can test this idea in your simulator to see if you get similar results. It doesn't make much difference but k = (317-6.5)/317 = 0.9795

@Andyaka yes I think the polarity is correct. You can see that on my schematics too. Unfortunately the Simulator shows a very good results even with less K eg K=0.96.

Yes I can see that on your schematic but, have you wound the winding correctly to match the dot notation. I ask this because you only gave a reference to the ferrite core. Maybe you should show how you wound it.

@Andyaka Yes right. No my winding matches the dot notion such that all dots refer to the starting point of the winding, and the windings were done all in the same direction. Also, I think the winding is correct as I have both +40v and -225v in the light load eg 1W on each rail.
